# How can I use pew in a bash/Python/Fabric/sh script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, virtualenv

I have recently begun using [pew](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pew) rather than [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) + [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

This is a nice alternative when working in an interactive shell. However, I still use virtualenvwrapper in my bash scripts [1], and I am considering writing some virtualenv-aware Python scripts [2].

Given that `pew workon` launches a new prompt, can I use it in shell [3] and Python scripts? If so, how?

[1] Using the following snippet, which is precisely what I'm trying to move away from:

```
# make sure we can workon (the path is Ubuntu-specific)
[[ $(type -t workon) == "function" ]] || source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper
```

[2] I'm still investigating which of plain Python, [Fabric](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric) and [sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh) will best suit my needs.

[3] Secretly, I would prefer to use it in fish rather than bash, but that seems esoteric :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally use pew only in an interactive shell, but there are some commands available for using pew along some scripts. Let's use this as an example:

```
>cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
which python
```

You can execute arbitrary code in a virtualenv with the `in` command:

```
pew in env which python
pew in env ./script.sh
```

(these two will do the same thing)

You can also use the `-d` flag to avoid activating it upon creation, thus you can use pew in a script like this:

```
pew new -d yourenv > /dev/null
pew in yourenv which python
```

I don't think that using something like [inve](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/2199506) gives you any real advantage in a shell script: if you have something like

```
#!/bin/sh
. ~/.virtualenvs/yourenv/bin/activate
which python
```

Sourcing a script won't pollute things outside the script that did the sourcing

OTOH: using pew or virtualenvwrapper might be useful for doing tasks lik copying/renaming environments. Any of the commands that don't end with a `invoke(inve)` [in the pew source code](https://github.com/berdario/invewrapper/blob/c1ef1ff7f3a5bde0dea8d43fa0a43af86c5d3e17/invewrapper/invewrapper.py#L133) should be fine to use, and for the others (new, mkproject, mktmpenv, cp) there should be a `--dont-activate` flag available.

(I just realized that the cp command doesn't have the `-d` flag, I might have to add it soon)

edit: further examples

```
> pew new -d dummy -i e
> pew in dummy python -me 2 "**" 53
dummy:
9007199254740992
> pew in dummy python helloworld.py 
dummy:
helloworld
```